# Strategic Complementarities and Multiplicity

Tags: macroeconomics, game-theory

Consider a coordination game, in which actions taken by players are strategic complements. Moreover, assume that actions are strong strategic complements, in that the slope of the *best response function* is greater than unity in some range, as demonstrated in the graph below. 
What is the intuition behind **multiple equilibria** in such a case? I understand the graphical intuition, but don't see any economic intuition.

[image: Source: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-462-advanced-macroeconomics-ii-spring-2004/lecture-notes/complementarties.pdf]

Source for the image: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-462-advanced-macroeconomics-ii-spring-2004/lecture-notes/complementarties.pdf